# Оформление класса

Tags: python, ооп, сокет

Нашёл кусок кода.
Собственно, всё работает, сервер и клиент весело общаются, но жутко неудобно всё это. Помогите обернуть всё это в один класс.

Т. е. внутри класса должны быть 3 функции:

1. Соединение с сокетом
2. Получение ответа от сервера
3. Отправка данных, получение ответа на запрос

Должно выйти так: соединяемся с сервером (получаем от него приглашение), вводим данные, в ответ получаем сообщение соответствующее введённым данным.

Этот кусок кода от telnet клиента на сокете.
Может я что-то неверно пытаюсь донести.
Пытаюсь привязать события к объектам gui, соответственно, нужны функции, а не процедуры:

```
# !python
import socket, select, string, sys

host = '0.0.0.0'
port = 8080

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, 
socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.settimeout(2)

# connect to remote host
try :
    s.connect((host, port))
except :
    print 'Unable to connect'
    sys.exit()

print 'Connected to remote host'

while 1:
    socket_list = [sys.stdin, s]

    # Get the list sockets which are readable
    read_sockets, write_sockets, error_sockets = select.select(socket_list , [], [])

    for sock in read_sockets:
        #incoming message from remote server 
        if sock == s:
            data = sock.recv(4096)
            if not data :
                print 'Connection closed'
                sys.exit()
            else :
                #print data
                sys.stdout.write(data)

        #user entered a message
        else :
            msg = sys.stdin.readline()
            s.send(msg)
```

Comment: В чём вопрос состоит? Вы не знаете как класс в Питоне создать? (если не знаете, то задайте отдельный вопрос, с минимальным примером кода, которые вы сами написали) Что вы хотите достичь, создавая класс здесь? Что значит "неудобно"? Приведите конкретный пример использования (как сейчас и как вы хотите -- до и после код) -- также словами опишите что пример делает.  По мелочи: в Питоне нет процедур, есть только функции, а что вы функциями называете, обычно называют методами, которые также как функции реализованы в Питоне.

Comment: уважаемый Aid, однако же useless dinosaur, понял суть моего вопроса )

Comment: вопрос понятней не стал. Если вы хотите в том же процессе GUI код выполнять (что как правило запускает некий цикл событий), то учитывая простоту серверного кода, можно `select` делегировать в GUI. К примеру, tkinter имеет [`createfilehandler()`](https://gist.github.com/zed/9294978),  в gtk есть [io_add_watch()](https://gist.github.com/zed/8a255e81eb87431c0e63#file-show-subprocess-output-io-watch-py). Чтобы ввод/вывод с консоли переносимо поддерживать, [можно потоки использовать для той же задачи](https://gist.github.com/zed/42324397516310c86288). (в примерах s/proc.stdout.read/sys.stdin.read/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В текущей реализации будет очень не удобно просто вынести код в отдельный класс, причиной для этого является `while 1`. Я бы посоветовал начать с того, чтобы вынести сначала все блоки внутри if\else в отдельные функции, дать им всем понятные имена, и когда дойдешь до бесконечного while, то надо будет смотреть в сторону [python threading](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/threading.html).

В итоге должен получиться класс, который создает поток, и в потоке вызывает методы для получения свежих сообщений и отправке своих.